# C++/Win32 Create a file in virtual memory

Tags: c++, winapi

How do I create a file in virtual memory and can I use normal file functions on it as CreateFile, WriteFile etc. ?

I am trying to implement a buffered file writer class, but the problem is managing a buffer that needs dynamic constant reallocation.

Comment: What do you mean under "create a file in virtual memory" ? All the memory available for a user-space process(an application) is virtual.

Comment: Perhaps he means to simulate the OS functionality , Virtual memory !!Kind of NUMA

Comment: I mean to create a file in process memory, allocated by windows, instead of in physical disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I think,you want the whole file inside Virtual Memory? But it feels a little difficult to me, and thus I have got another workaround for it.You can use [VirtualAllocExNuma](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366891(v=vs.85).aspx) to load your file in memory and work on it.Since Virtual Memory is that part of the memory which is just supposed to be retained by OS but in physically it is scattered around different Non Uniform memory devices besides RAM.
It is not a filesystem where you can save your files and how it is managed is also difficult to be traced(at least for me!).

*VirtualAllocExNuma*

> Reserves or commits a region of memory within the virtual address
>   space of the specified process, and specifies the NUMA node for the
>   physical memory.

Comment: OK and so once I have reserved this space in virtual memory, how can I redirect the function WriteFile to write in it?

Comment: You don't have to write using WriteFile,this is just a memory block and you know how easy is it to write in a free space using pointers or memcpy.Keep saving whatever you want in it,and then flush this memory to the file using WriteFile.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a pipe. They are also considered "files" by the os, and you use WriteFile and ReadFile with them:

```
HANDLE               hReadPipe;
HANDLE               hWritePipe;
CreatePipe(&hReadPipe, &hWritePipe , 0, 0);
WriteFile(hWritePipe, "hello", 5, 0, 0);

int sz = GetFileSize(hReadPipe, 0);
assert(sz == 5);
char out[5];
ReadFile(hReadPipe, out, 5, 0,0);
```

You can even convert them to C FILE* handles with something along the lines of _open_osfhandle if desired.

Answer (score 2):

For C++, just use a `std::[io]stringstream`.

For the Windows API, you can call [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx) with the [`FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx#caching_behavior) flag, and it'll *try* (but not guarantee) to keep the content in RAM instead of on disk.