# Can I create a file in Windows that only exists in memory - and if so, how?

Tags: windows, winapi, temporary-files, memory-mapped-files

<sub>This question is not a duplicate of any of these existing questions:</sub>

- <sub>[How can I store an object File that only exists in memory as a file inside of my storage system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59665437/how-can-i-store-an-object-file-that-only-exists-in-memory-as-a-file-inside-of-my) - This question is not about Java's `File` API.</sub>
- <sub>[Temp file that exists only in RAM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551595/temp-file-that-exists-only-in-ram) - This is close to what I'm asking, except the OP isn't asking how to create files from memory for the purposes of sharing passing them to child-processes</sub>
- <sub>I'm not asking about Win32's Memory-mapped File either - as they're essentially *the opposite* of what I'm after: a memory-mapped file is a file-on disk that's mapped to a process' virtual memory space - whereas what I want is a file that exists in the OS' filesystem (but not the disk's physical filesystem) like a mount-point and that file's data is mapped to an existing buffer in memory.</sub>

  - <sub>I.e., with Memory Mapped Files, writing/writing to a byte at a particular buffer address and offset in memory will cause the byte at the same offset from the start of the file to be modified - but the file physically exists on-disk, which isn't what I want.</sub>

To elaborate and to provide context:

- I have an ASP.NET Core server-side application that receives request streams sized between 1 and 10MB on a regular basis. This program will run only on Windows / Windows Server, so using Windows-specific functionality is fine.
- 75% of the time my application just reads through these streams by itself and that's it.
- But a minority of the time it needs to have a separate applications read the data which it starts using `Process.Start` and passing the file-name as a command-line argument.

  - It passes the data to these separate applications by saving the stream to a temporary file on-disk and passing the filename of that stream.
  - Unfortunately it can't write the content to the child-process's `stdin` because some of the those programs expect a file on-disk rather than reading from `stdin`.
- Additionally, while the machine it's running on has lots of RAM (so keeping the streams buffered in-memory is fine) it has slow *spinning-rust* HDDs, which is further reason to avoid temporary files on-disk.
- I'd like to avoid unnecessary buffering and copies - ideally I'd like to stream the entire 1-10MB request into a single in-memory buffer, and then expose that same buffer to other processes *and* use that same buffer as the backing for a temporary file.
- If I were on Linux, I could use `tmpfs` - it isn't perfect:

  - To my knowledge, an existing process can't instruct the OS to take an existing region of its virtual-memory and map a file in `tmpfs` to that memory region, instead `tmpfs` still requires that the file be populated by writing (i.e. copying) all of the data to its file-descriptor - which is counter to the aim of having a zero-copy system.
- Windows' built-in RAM-disk functionality is limited to providing the basis for a RAM-disk implementation via a third-party device-driver - I'm surprised that Microsoft never shipped Windows with a built-in RAM-disk GUI or API, especially given their relative simplicity.

  - [The `ImDisk` program](http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/#ImDisk) is an implementation of a RAM-disk using Microsoft's RAM-disk driver platform, but as far as I can tell while it's more like `tmpfs` in that it can create a file that exists only in-memory, it doesn't allow the file's data to be backed by a buffer directly accessible to a running process (or a shared-memory buffer).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C - create file in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249610/), [C++/Win32 Create a file in virtual memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938083/), etc

Comment: There seems no such user application level API for this purpose. It can be done via implementing a driver. Could you mind sharing the reason of using RAM? For better read/write speed?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT I want to pass 1GB of data from one process to a new child-process: but that process can only accept a filename instead of passing it through `stdin` - and I'd like to avoid copying that 1GB around in-memory.

Answer (score 4):

[`CreateFileMapping`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-createfilemappingw) with `hFile = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` "*creates a file mapping object of a specified size that is backed by the system paging file instead of by a file in the file system*".

From Raymond Chen's [The source of much confusion: “backed by the system paging file”](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130301-00/?p=5093):

> In other words, “backed by the system paging file” just means “handled like regular virtual memory.”
>
> If the memory is freed before it ever gets paged out, then it will never get written to the system paging file.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know you could create a page-file backed memory-mapped file - however how can I map that file to an _existing_ shared-memory buffer? I see I can use `MapViewOfFileEx` to map a memory-mapped file (including a pagefile-backed mapped file) into my process' memory space, but I guess I'd have to use `MapViewOfFileEx` *first* and store the buffer into there - but I wonder what would happen if I passed-in a pointer to a buffer already allocated.

Comment: Update: turns out you can't. The documentation for `MapViewOfFileEx` states: "the function succeeds if the specified memory region is not already in use by the calling process". Bummer.

Comment: @Dai Depending on the use-case, you may be able to do it the other way around and use the mapping for sharing, with [Creating Named Shared Memory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/creating-named-shared-memory) and [OpenFileMapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-openfilemappinga).

Comment: A paging-file backed mapping isn't a regular file that a program can open, so it doesn't satisfy the requirements. The program could create a regular file with the attribute [`FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea?redirectedfrom=MSDN#caching-behavior) to avoid writing to disk as much as possible.

Comment: @ErykSun `isn't a regular file` Right, of course. On the other hand, no file "*that only exists in memory*" (as the title says) can be a "*regular*" file. A named mapping can, however, be opened even though not with `CreateFile`.

Comment: A file can exist just in memory if it's on a ramdisk. Dai mentions this, but Microsoft doesn't distribute a ramdisk driver with Windows. If Dai is willing to use a 3rd party tool such as ImDisk, a file on the ramdisk could be mapped into the process virtual memory.

Comment: The OP introduces another constraint, though: The file contents need to be mapped into memory at a predefined location (that presumably aliases an existing buffer).